# GetUpdateServer not found in AdminProxy class

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, windows-update

```
$servername='DC1'
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration") | Out-Null
$wsus = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.AdminProxy]::getUpdateServer($servername,$False)
```

This is the powershell comand that I am trying to run. But getting an exception as -

```
    Exception calling "GetUpdateServer" with "2" argument(s): "The type initializer for 
'Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.Constants' threw an exception."
At line:3 char:1
+ $wsus = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.AdminProxy]::getUpdateServer($s ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeInitializationException
```

When I tried refrencing the Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.dll and tried to use GetUpdateServer method, I could not find the method in AdminProxy Class. This is the line of code-

```
    using Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration;
using Microsoft.UpdateServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
[ClassInterfaceAttribute(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[GuidAttribute("6391AFBB-45A8-4107-A154-F27DB8F03049")]
public sealed class AdminProxy
{

}

namespace WindowsApplication2
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IUpdateServer obj;
            obj = AdminProxy.GetUpdateServer();


        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that you must have the WSUS Administration Console installed to access the required assemblies. have you installed them?

Comment: Yes I do have Wsus administrative console installed.

Comment: Are you running your PowerShell console "as an administrator"? I've seen issues with UAC that have caused this error to occur and are resolved when you right-click on PowerShell and select "run as administrator"

Answer (score 0):

As user boeprox pointed out in the comments, you need to run the PowerShell console as an administrator.